# Struts form automatically submitted when using validate() method

Tags: java, struts, struts-config

I am using struts 1.2. My struts flow is working properly but when I am using validate() method of action form for validation. my form is automatically submitted. and this validation method get called.

I am not sure this is normal behavior of struts or some configuration are missing in my application.

Please help me to understand it.
following are the config and code

```
<action path="/Postaddd" 
            type="bseller.postadd.PostaddAction" 
            parameter="dispatch"
            scope="request"
            validate="true"
            name="PostadddForm">
        <forward name="posterror" path="ordererror.page"/>
        <forward name="successPost" path="bseller.successPost.page"/>  

    </action>       public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) 
    {


        Logger  log= Logger.getLogger("BSELLER_APPLICATION");
        log.info("validate method called");
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

          log.info("Email Id: " + getEmailid()); 
          if(!Validation.isValidEmailAddress(getEmailid()))
                  {
              errors.add("emailid", new ActionMessage("prompt.email.error"));
                  }
          if(!Validation.isPhoneNumberValid(getMobile()))
          {
              errors.add("mobile", new ActionMessage("prompt.contactno.error"));
          }

          if(!Validation.isNumeric(getPrice()))
          {
              errors.add("price", new ActionMessage("prompt.price.error"));
          }


        return errors;
    }
```

///////////////

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" prefix="display" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c"%>

<%@ page import="bseller.utils.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%@page import="bseller.utils.CategorydetailObject"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.IterateTag"%><head>
<title><bean:message key="homepage.title" /></title>
<html:base />
<style type="text/css">
@import url("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/main.css");
@import url("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/submitpost.css");

</style>

<script language="javascript" src="jquery_mini.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/Ajax_Function.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">



    var name = "#floatMenu";


    var menuYloc = null;

        $(document).ready(function(){

            menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
            $(window).scroll(function () { 
                offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
                $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:500,queue:false});
            });
        }); 
     </script>
     <script>
     function ret_home()
     {
     alert("home");
     return false;
     }
     function ret_aboutus()
     {
     alert("about us");
     return false;
     }
     function ret_contactus()
     {
     alert("contact us");
     return false;
     }

     function getSubcatValue(categoryValue)
     {
     //alert(document.getElementById("categorySelect").Value);
     document.getElementById("categorySelect").Value =categoryValue;
     //alert(document.getElementById("categorySelect").Value);
      //alert(categoryValue);
      //var data="catvalue="+categoryValue;
      //alert(data);
      //datafromajax="";
     // alert("before1"+datafromajax);
      var url="Subcategory_Ajax.jsp?catvalue="+categoryValue;
      sendRequest(url);
      //alert("after"+datafromajax);
      //datafromajax="";
      document.getElementById("categorySelect").Value="";
     }

     /*function setUploadImageOption(ordertype);
     {

      if(ordertype=="Required")
      {
          //document.getElementById("UploadImage").visible= false;
          document.getElementById('UploadImage').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
      }
     }*/

     function onchangeSubcat(subcatValue)
     {
      // alert(subcatValue);
      //alert(document.getElementById("subCatSelect").Value);
       document.getElementById("subCatSelect").Value =subcatValue;
       //alert(document.getElementById("subCatSelect").Value);
       //subcatValue=subcatValue;
     }



     //populatedropdown
     </script>



<style type="text/css">
body {

    height:2000px;
    color:#111;
    font:10px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Trebuchet MS", verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    #floatMenu {
        position:absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:55%;
        margin-left:235px;
        width:200px;
        }
        #floatMenu ul {
            margin-bottom:20px;
            }
            #floatMenu ul li a {
                display:block;
                border:1px solid #999;
                background-color:#000;
                background:'images/tab_bg1.gif'
                border-left:6px solid #999;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#ccc;
                padding:5px 5px 5px 25px;
            }
            #floatMenu ul li a:hover {
                color:#fff;
                background-color:#333333;
            }
            #floatMenu ul.menu1 li a:hover {
                border-color:#09f;
            }
            #floatMenu ul.menu2 li a:hover {
                border-color:#9f0;
            }
            #floatMenu ul.menu3 li a:hover {
                border-color:#f09;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<span id="er"></span>
<%!

List l;   
HashMap<String ,ArrayList<CategorydetailObject>> hm =null; %>


<%
 try
{
hm =(HashMap<String ,ArrayList<CategorydetailObject>>)config.getServletContext().getAttribute("PRODUCTS");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
%>
<input type="hidden" name="subcatfromajax" id="subcatfromajax"></input>
<DIV class=city><DIV id=welcome></DIV><DIV id=main><DIV id=block><DIV id=header><font size=4 color=blue >
Post Your Advertisement</DIV><DIV class=blank5></DIV><DIV class=blank5></DIV>

<html:messages id="" />
<html:form action="/Postaddd.do?dispatch=submitPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width='98%'background='images/background_city.gif' border=0><TBODY>
    <TR> 
    <TD><div class="post_ad_fonts">Email</div><div style="float:left">
  <input style="width:162px" type="text" maxlength="64" name="emailid" id="emailid" class="post_ad_field" value='' />  
  </div>
<div class="blank10"></div>
  </TD>
    </TR>


    <TR> 

    <TD><DIV id=bb1><div class="post_ad_fonts">City</div><div style="float:left">
<select class="post_ad_field" style="width:165px" name='citySelectBox' id='citySelectBox'>
<option id='0' name='0' value='0'>Select City</option>
<option name='22' id='22' value='Ahmedabad' >Ahmedabad</option><option name='211001' id='211001' value='Allahabad' >Allahabad</option><option name='23' id='23' value='Bangalore' >Bangalore</option><option name='462001' id='462001' value='Bhopal' >Bhopal</option><option name='24' id='24' value='Chandigarh' >Chandigarh</option><option name='25' id='25' value='Chennai' >Chennai</option><option name='26' id='26' value='Coimbatore' >Coimbatore</option><option name='27' id='27' value='Delhi' >Delhi</option><option name='403108' id='403108' value='Goa' >Goa</option><option name='132222' id='132222' value='Gurgaon' >Gurgaon</option><option name='580020' id='580020' value='Hubli' >Hubli</option><option name='28' id='28' value='Hyderabad' >Hyderabad</option><option name='142222' id='142222' value='Indore' >Indore</option><option name='152222' id='152222' value='Jaipur' >Jaipur</option><option name='144001' id='144001' value='Jalandhar' >Jalandhar</option><option name='831001' id='831001' value='Jamshedpur' >Jamshedpur</option><option name='421301' id='421301' value='Kalyan' >Kalyan</option><option name='208001' id='208001' value='Kanpur' >Kanpur</option><option name='29' id='29' value='Kochi' >Kochi</option><option name='30' id='30' value='Kolkata' >Kolkata</option><option name='162222' id='162222' value='Lucknow' >Lucknow</option><option name='141001' id='141001' value='Ludhiana' >Ludhiana</option><option name='625001' id='625001' value='Madurai' >Madurai</option><option name='575001' id='575001' value='Mangalore' >Mangalore</option><option name='31' id='31' value='Mumbai' >Mumbai</option><option name='32' id='32' value='Mysore' >Mysore</option><option name='172222' id='172222' value='Nagpur' >Nagpur</option><option name='422001' id='422001' value='Nashik' >Nashik</option><option name='400701' id='400701' value='NaviMumbai' >NaviMumbai</option><option name='201301' id='201301' value='Noida' selected>Noida</option><option name='800001' id='800001' value='Patna' >Patna</option><option name='33' id='33' value='Pune' >Pune</option><option name='360001' id='360001' value='Rajkot' >Rajkot</option><option name='182222' id='182222' value='Surat' >Surat</option><option name='400601' id='400601' value='Thane' >Thane</option><option name='620015' id='620015' value='Trichy' >Trichy</option><option name='695001' id='695001' value='Trivandrum' >Trivandrum</option><option name='390001' id='390001' value='Vadodara' >Vadodara</option><option name='520001' id='520001' value='Vijayawada' >Vijayawada</option><option name='531001' id='531001' value='Vizag' >Vizag</option></select>
<input type='hidden' name='city' id='city' value='201301'/>
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>
</div>
</TD></TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Category</div>
    <div style="float:left">
    <select class="post_ad_field" style="width:165px" name='categorySelect' id='categorySelect'"  onchange="getSubcatValue(this.value);">
    <option id='0' value='0'>Select Category</option>
    <%  
    Set<Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<CategorydetailObject>>> set =hm.entrySet(); 

    for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<CategorydetailObject>> me: set)
    {
       String cat= me.getKey();
    %>

    <option name="<%=cat %>" id="<%=cat %>" value="<%=cat %>">  <%=cat %></option>
    <% 
    }

    %>       
     </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='categorySelect' id='categorySelect' value=''/>
    </div>
    <div class="blank10"></div>
    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">SubCategory</div>
    <div style="float:left">
    <select class="post_ad_field" style="width:165px" name='subCatSelect' id='subCatSelect' onchange="onchangeSubcat(this.value);">
    <option id='0' value='0'>Select SubCategory</option>
    </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='subCatSelect' id='subCatSelect' value=''/>

    </div>
    <div class="blank10"></div>
    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <DIV id=bb1><div class="post_ad_fonts">Head Line</div>
    <div style="float:left">
  <input style="width:440px" type="text" maxlength="64" name="headline" id="headline" class="post_ad_field"  value='' />  
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>
</div>

    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>
    <DIV id=bb1><div class="post_ad_fonts">Description</div>
    <div style="float:left;width :440px;">
  <table border="0" style="margin:0px"><tr><td><div id="showbar">Loading Html Editor...<img src="images/ajax_loader.gif" alt="loading"/></div></td></tr></table>
<textarea name="description" id="description " onfocus="if(this.value=='Adding more detail here will help you get more responses.')this.value='';" style="width:440px;height:170px">Adding more detail here will help you get more responses.</textarea>

</div>
</div>


    </TD>
</TR>


<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Mobile No.<br/><span style="font-weight:normal">(Optional)</span></div>
<div style="float:left">
  <input style="width:162px" type="text" maxlength="14" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="post_ad_field" value="" />    
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>

    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Price<br/><span style="font-weight:normal">(Optional)</span></div>
<div style="float:left">
  <input style="width:162px" type="text" maxlength="14" name="price" id="price" class="post_ad_field" value="" />    
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>

    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Owner type<br/></div>
<div style="float:left">
  <select class="post_ad_field" style="width:165px" name='owner' id='owner'>
<option id='0' name='0' value='0'>Individual</option>
<option name='22' id='22' value='Ahmedabad' >Broker</option></select>
<input type='hidden' name='ownertype' id='ownertype' value='Individual'/>
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>
</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Order type<br/></div>
<div style="float:left">
<select class="post_ad_field" style="width:165px" name='order' id='order'">
<option id='0' name='0' value='Available'>Available</option>
<option name='22' id='22' value='Required' >Required</option></select>
<input type='hidden' name='ordertype' id='ordertype' value='Available'/>
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>
</TD>
</TR>





<TR>
    <TD>
    <div class="post_ad_fonts">Upload Image<br/></div>
<div style="float:left" id="UploadImage">

  <html:file property="image1"></html:file> 
  <html:file property="image2"></html:file>
  <html:file property="image3"></html:file>
<input type="file" name="image4">  
</div>
<div class="blank10"></div>

    </TD>
</TR>
<tr><td><div class="post_ad_fonts"><br/></div><div style="float:middle"><html:submit>POST ORDER</html:submit></div> </td></tr>
</TBODY></TABLE></html:form></DIV></DIV></DIV><DIV class=blank10></DIV></DIV></DIV>


<div id="floatMenu">
  <ul class="menu1">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return ret_home();"> Home </a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu2">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return ret_aboutus();"> About Us </a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;"> </a></li>-->
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu3">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return ret_contactus();"> Contact Us </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you requesting /Postaddd ? If yes, then it's normal.

Comment: I am requesting a jsp in which we have a form which is target to /postadd, but when i am hitting that jsp. that form automatically getting submitted.(When  I am using validate()) otherwise its working fine.

Comment: You need to check the jsp, if there is some javascript doing so.

Comment: Hi I have uploaded jsp file also, I checked and could not find anything, the point is what is the relation of validate() method with form submission.

Comment: I have to say this jsp breaks MVC. It even includes java code. You can try to only leave the form html for debugging to see if it still auto submits or not.

Comment: Ok, but what is the role of validate method for autosubmission, because when I remove that it works....

Answer (score 0):

the validate method of actionform is always called when the form is submitted. you cannot manually call it unless you r reimplementing struts in ur own way. if u want a method to do the same work as the validate method, move the code of the validate method into another method and call it in the validate method. I do not completely understand what you are trying to do so please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. I am mentioning validate() method called because. my form is getting submitted automatically when requesting for the corresponding jsp.  and this is happening only when I am using validate() method. and when I am not using this method its working. So I am totally confused why this is happening. please help me to understand it. thanks for you time

Comment: can you share the action mapping specification for this from ur struts-config.xml? also it would be great to see where you where using the validate method.

Comment: can't see it. not yet peer reviewed i guess

Comment: I  can see it, will you please check it.

Comment: see the order error.page is another action mapping i guess, so u better change it to a jsp location. and i thought u were using the validate method manually in some location.. if so please change that using ur Validation.is.... methods

Comment: @Piyush let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2712/discussion-between-abhishek-and-piyush)